# Is there a function in R where I can give it a number, and it will return the squares it lies in between?

Tags: r, math

Forgive me if this is a simple problem, I only started coding in R a few weeks ago. I want to be able to, given a number (say 20), find the nearest upper and lower squares (16 and 25). Any suggestions are appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
get_nearest_squares <- function(n){

square_root <- sqrt(n)
lower_square <- floor(square_root)**2
upper_square <- ceiling(square_root)**2

nearest_squares <- list(lower = lower_square, upper = upper_square)

return(nearest_squares)
}
```